# How to find my existing My SQL password for bitnami

Tags: macos

I want to create admin account in Zoomla 2.5.1, there I am asked to fill a form.
and by chance I forgot my existing My SQL password for bitnami, and so I am having trouble creating the Admin account.

Answer (score 0):

You try this:
https://bitnami.com/password/new

You lost password of bitnami or on server of mysql?

If you lost a password of any program (memorized) in your mac open your application folder > utility > keychain.
In the top-left panel choose login and in the bottom-left choose all elements.
In the right panel you see all your element sort by name, double click on bitnami element and choose "show password".

I hope it's work for you